# Categorize installed apps into a GridView in Android

Tags: java, android, gridview

How can I categorize the installed apps on an Android device (Not including system apps) into a GridView?

For example: I have 2 GridViews in an XML layout, one called Games and one called Google, for the GridView named "games", I display the installed applications in the category games into the GridView. For the GridView names "Google", I have the installed applications under the category Google (gapps) into the GridView. While getting the icon for the application as well.

Can I have that done with a 2 GridViews (displaying the application icon, and when clicking the icon, the application opens)?

Thanks